How to test the post method in FastAPI when it has various logic inside?
My main.py looks like this:
from retriever import get_filtered_data

@app.post(
        "/getApi",
          response_class=JSONResponse,
          tags=["Some tags"],
          description="Some description"
        )
async def get_json_api(request: Basemodel,
                            params: Params = Depends()) -> Page:
    
    try:
        response = get_filtered_data('param_1',
                                    request=request)

        return paginate(response['items'],
                        additional_data={
                            "ABC": 123
                        },
                        params=params
                        )
    
    except Exception as exception:
        return HttpErrorResponse(data=f'ERROR details = {exception}',
                                 timestamp=datetime.now())

I want to write test case for the above, the thing is get_filtered_data has all the logic which does the following:

Connect to AzureSQL
Retrieve the data

The final response is passed to paginate.
My current test case looks like this:
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock, ANY

def test_get_json_property(self):
       mocked_response = requests.Response()
       
       with patch("requests.post", return_value=mocked_response) as mocked_request:
        response = self.client.post("/getApi",
                                    json={"in_filter": {"test_key": "test_value"}},
                                    headers={"content-type": "application/json"})

        mocked_request.return_value = {"items": {"test_key": "test_value"}}

        assert response.status_code == 200
        self.assertEqual(response.json(), mocked_response)

The result returns 422 error code with the below output:
{'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 'items'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': <HttpErrorResponse.HttpErrorResponse object at 0x000001FD7E0C17B0>}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 'total'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': <HttpErrorResponse.HttpErrorResponse object at 0x000001FD7E0C17B0>}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 'page'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': <HttpErrorResponse.HttpErrorResponse object at 0x000001FD7E0C17B0>}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 'size'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': <HttpErrorResponse.HttpErrorResponse object at 0x000001FD7E0C17B0>}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 'links'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': <HttpErrorResponse.HttpErrorResponse object at 0x000001FD7E0C17B0>}

Can someone guide in how to tackle this scenario

Using = Depends() would tell FastAPI to expect params as query parameters, not JSON data, which you seem to be sending on client side. Please have a look at this answer, as well as this answer and this answer for more details.

Thanks @Chris for your response, I see that if I pass the request without params, it gives "params field required", in error.

When you are testing routes, you need to mock all other dependencies, like services and others.
What you want when testing a route is to test if it will return exactly what you want if your dependency returns something correct, raise an error, etc.
Based on the code you provided, you just need to use unittest.mock to patch get_filtered_data (you don't want to test azure and other services in an unit test):
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from unittest import mock

from app import app


def mock_filtered_data(*args, request=None):
    return {
        "items": [
            {"id": 1}
        ]
    }


def mock_filtered_data_err(*args, request=None):
    raise Exception()


@mock.patch("app.get_filtered_data", mock_filtered_data)
def test_get_json_property(*args):
    client = TestClient(app)
    response = client.post("/getApi", json={"in_filter": {"test_key": "test_value"}}, headers={"content-type": "application/json"})

    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert len(response.json()) == 1


@mock.patch("app.get_filtered_data", mock_filtered_data_err)
def test_get_json_property_should_return_500_if_get_filtered_data_raises_exception(*args):
    client = TestClient(app)
    response = client.post("/getApi", json={"in_filter": {"test_key": "test_value"}}, headers={"content-type": "application/json"})

    assert response.status_code == 500

Since you didn't provide you file/folder structure and the other methods implementations, I made a few "mocks" to make your example work:
Folder structure:

app.py
retriever.py
test_get_api.py

# retriever.py
def get_filtered_data(*args, **kwargs):
    return {
        "items": [
            {"id": 1},
            {"id": 2},
            {"id": 3}
        ]
    }



# app.py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import Depends
from fastapi.exceptions import HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel

from retriever import get_filtered_data


app = FastAPI()


class Basemodel(BaseModel):
    pass


class Params(BaseModel):
    pass


class Page(BaseModel):
    pass


def paginate(*args, **kwargs):
    return JSONResponse(args[0])


@app.post("/getApi", response_class=JSONResponse, tags=["Some tags"], description="Some description")
async def get_json_api(request: Basemodel, params: Params = Depends()) -> Page:
    
    try:
        response = get_filtered_data('param_1', request=request)

        return paginate(
            response['items'],
            additional_data={
                "ABC": 123
            },
            params=params
        )
    
    except Exception as exception:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500)

Now if you use pytest:
> pytest
collected 2 items

test_get_api.py ..
== 2 passed in 1.28s ==


Thanks @Rafael for you response and such detailed solution. I tried this approach  and mocked the get_filtered_data (which resides in a different block); I still get the same error as I pasted before.
It seems that while attempting for pagination, it expects the default fields like page, size, links etc (which I tried to add in the mocked response). I need those fields in my actual response.
If I override the pagination as per your code, the test then passes but i do not get those fields in the reposnse.

@iambhaswar I don't know the actual code of pagination, so it's a little difficult to answer. But you'll either mock your pagination function if it do something out of your testing scope or add a proper response to the mocked get_filtered_data.

Thanks @Rafael for the info and help, really helpful. I will try to do on similar lines
